# How can I reset the path to the result appearance of an object distorted with effects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, illustrator-effects

I have a simple rectangle with a couple effects: distort, rounded corners.

I'd now like to add some anchor points and adjust the path of this object. How can I get the path to wrap around the rounded, distorted rectangle instead of the original box?

[image: distorted rectangle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by selecting the object, then going to the menu <kbd>Object > Expand Appearance</kbd>.

Comment: Might be a good idea to duplicate the object first, just in case you need to backtrack later.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate your object (in case you need to tweak your original shape)

Select your shape, then choose **Object / Flatten Transparency**

These settings will do:
[image: Flattening settings]